# Problems with dependencies in SystemJS

Tags: angular, systemjs, sigma.js

I am having trouble importing the [sigma-forceAtlas](https://github.com/jacomyal/sigma.js/tree/master/plugins/sigma.layout.forceAtlas2) js library which makes reference to a global sigma object. This is my system.js config:

```
map: {
 'sigma': 'node_modules/sigma',
 'sigma-forceAtlas2':'node_modules/sigma/build/plugins'
},
packages : {
'sigma': { main: 'build/sigma.require.js', defaultExtension: 'js'},
'sigma-forceAtlas2':{ main:'sigma.layout.forceAtlas2',defaultExtension: 'min.js' }
}
meta : {
  'sigma-forceAtlas2': {
    deps: ['sigma']
   }
}
```

When I try to do System.import('sigma-forceAtlas2') I get a sigma is not declared error

Comment: are you sure that sigma gets exposes as a global var?

Comment: Normally it does. If I import it with script tags in the index.html, it does. With my current SystemJs it doesnt get exposed

Comment: then maybe you need to specify an exports meta as defined here https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs/blob/master/docs/config-api.md#meta

Comment: I replaced the meta object with                                                                  this: meta : {
    'sigma': {
      format: 'global',
      exports: 'sigma'
    },
    'sigma-forceAtlas2': {
      deps: ['sigma']
    }
  } but I'm still having the same error

Comment: in the network panel of the dev tools, do you see sigma being loaded before sigma-forceAtlas2?

Comment: No. Sigma is being loaded after sigma-forceAtlas2

Answer (score 0):

The problem was being caused because the meta object only maps to names but does not add the main information from the packages object. So, instead I've used the whole paths like this:

```
meta : {
  'node_modules/sigma/build/sigma.require.js': {
     format: 'global',
     exports: 'sigma'
   },
  'node_modules/sigma/build/plugins/sigma.layout.forceAtlas2.min.js': {
     deps: ['sigma']
    }
  }
```